# Pip module installation issue

Tags: python, pip

I'm having difficulty installing modules using pip for python. The exact error message is:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shapefile (from versions: DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for shapefile
```

When I type:

```
pip install -vvv shapefile
```

I get a 404 status code saying:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/shapefile/: 404 Client Error
```

I've browsed around and have seen there is a config file that allows you to change where pip installs modules from. However, I can't find this file in my /.pip folder.

Does anyone know how I would go about fixing my pip configuration so that I can install packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list that matches your module name: [PyPI search result for shapefile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=shapefile&submit=search)

Maybe the module is called `pyshapefile` not just `shapefile`.

```
pip install pyshapefile
```